# Ресурсы данных в формате csv

Tags: python, csv

Я начал заниматься Data Science (В частности на Python), и когда я познакомился с Pandas и работой с CSV файлами, мне стало интересно, где их брать, для работы и анализа над ними. Посоветуйте ресурсы для загрузки CSV файлов на разные темы.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/top-sources-for-machine-learning-datasets-bb6d0dc3378b - 10 секунд времени и Google творят чудеса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеется очень много классных сайтов с открытыми данными в формате csv, чего то сакрального там особо не найдется но для тренировки подойдет

http://opendata.by/ - белорусский сайт открытых данных на котором можно найти нужную базу по разным темам, от постройки домов до демографической ситуации(сам им пользовался)

https://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/ - сайт российского центробанка на котором можно найти различные данные связанные с финансами курсами валют и акциями(на случай если решите написать нейросеть предсказывающую курсы валют):)